# In statistics using a regression analysis in SPSS - - variables are hunger and amount of dancing

Tags: statistics

In statistics using a regression analysis in SPSS - - variables are hunger and amount of dancing. Which would be the dependent and independent variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the problem and what you are trying to achieve.  I could see this going either way, without further information on the problem.  Just guessing, I would say hunger is the dependent variable (the more you dance, the more calories you burn, and the hungrier you get).

Hope this helps!

Comment: The opposite would be funny to consider !